# How to add a MapActivity into MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-mapview

In my Application, I want to show a 'Map' like below in the picture, so is there any special method to add this Because we can't add one **Activity** into another **Activity** so I am searching for a special method or technique, no doubt many application are using this but I am not familiar with that method, I searched but could not find any appropriate answer.

[image]

Comment: `MapActivity` is just an Activity which have a `MapView` you can add `MapView` in any Activity.  By looking at the UI its look like a [Lite mode map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Activity` can never host an `Activity`. You can only add a [`MapFragment`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment).